# how can i remove the selected list item from combobox when i open the combobox next time

Tags: javascript, combobox, sapui5

I have a scenario with combo box value. I just wanted to know how should I remove or hide the already selected value of a combo box the next time i use this combo box. I mean once I have selected a value from a combo box, I would not be able to see that selected value again when I click the combo box the next time. I have around 400+ items in the combobox list. can anyone give me some code related to this, in sapui5 and javascript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `selectionChange` event of `ComoboBox` to remove selected item from current data and set modified data new `ComoboBox`.

```
var combo = e.getSource();
this.data.values.splice(combo.indexOfItem(combo.getSelectedItem()), 1);
if (this.data.values.length === 0)
   {return;}
var newCombo = new sap.m.ComboBox({
   selectionChange: this.fn.bind(this)
});
newCombo.bindItems("/values", new sap.ui.core.Item({
   text: "{val}",
   key: "{val}"
}));
this.byId("page").addContent(newCombo);
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/sibiqog/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: hello Dopedev, Thanks for your reply, i have a scenario here, where if i select one combobox item, there creates another combobox with the same list item, i dont want the first selected list item to be appeared on the next opened combobox list item., like the way i have around 400 listitems. every time i select the list item the item should not be visible on the next combobox list item.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do that but eventually it will create around 400 `ComboBox` controls if you select each of them, are you sure with your requirement?

Comment: Yes, user can create number of records as much the length of combobox listitem, so eventually it will create the number of comboboxes, but once user selects the list item, that should not be visible in next selection. i'm unable to attach my screenshots of it here, please give me your email id, i will send the detailed screenshots of it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check modified answer and demo.

Comment: Sorry, Dopedev, i was busy with some other issue.. i was not implemented the code in my project, once i implement, i will make a comment on that.